# What does the "do" control construct do in Scheme?

Tags: algorithm, scheme, procedure

I've ran against a Scheme procedure, that works using a so-called `do` procedure, but I don't know how it works, or how it is implemented. If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it.
The code is the following:

```
(define (storage-move-right vector i j)
  (do ((idx j (- idx 1)))
    O(n)
      ((< idx i))
        (vector-set! vector (+ idx 1) (vector-ref vector idx))))
```

Comment: It's explained in the [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) documentation.

Comment: This is a standard macro, just read your interpreter's [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=do#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._do%29%29).

Comment: The line with `O(n)` is probably not supposed to be there.  `do` is not a procedure and it's just [syntax sugar for a recursive procedure](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_7.3) so using named `let` I find more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The "missing" looping constructs while, repeat-until and for

### Problem

The control constructs `while`, `repeat-until` and `for` are present in most mainstream programming languages, but nevertheless they are not found in the Scheme standard. What is used in Scheme?

### Solution

These constructs can all be "emulated" by using normal (tail recursive) function calls. However since these constructs are used so often, there are some more convenient syntactical sugar available. The two most used constructs are using `named let` and the `do` construct.

It is best to think of the `do` construct as a glorified "do-until"-loop. The simplest form of `do` is:

```
(do ()
  [test return-exp]
  exp
  ...)
```

If `return-exp` is omitted then the returned value is `void`, "the invisible value" (so named because it isn't printed in the interaction window).

At the beginning of each loop the test expression is evaluated. If it's non false, then `return-exp` is evaluated and its return value is the value of the entire `do`-loop. If the test is false, the body expressions are evaluated sequentially. After the evaluation of the last body expression, a new loop is started.

```
; Example 1
; WARNING: This is not good style.
;          A better solution is found below.

                                  ; Pseudo Code
(define i 0)                      ; i := 0
(do ()                            ; do 
  [(= i 5)]                       ;   until i=5
  (display i)                     ;       display i
  (set! i (+ i 1)))               ;       i := i +1

; displays: 01234
```

The alternative to `do` namely "named let" is a variant on the syntax of `let` which provides a more general looping construct than do and may also be used to express recursions. It has the almost the same syntax as a normal `let`, but the variable name can be used in the body to repeat the execution of body with new values for `var1` ... by calling name with the new values.

```
(let name ([var1 exp1]
           ...)
   body
   ...)
```

The list of variables can be empty.
Rewriting a normal while -loop is now easy:

```
while test           (do ()                 (let while ()
  begin                [(not test)]           (when test
    exp1               exp1                      exp1
    exp2               exp2                      exp2
    ...                ...)                      ...
  end                                            (while)))
```

The `(void)` expression evaluates to the "invisible" value to indicate that the return value is not meant to be used. It is not printed by the interaction window (the REPL).

To write a `for`-loop with `do` requires us to look at the next simplest form of do:

```
(do ([var start-exp next-exp])
  [test return-exp]
  exp
  ...)
```

The evaluation of the `do`-expression begins with the evaluation of `start-exp`. The result is bound to the variable `i` which is visible in both `next-exp` as well as `test`, `return-exp` and the `body` expressions. When the loop is restarted `next-exp` is evaluated and the variable `var` is rebound to the result, before the `test` expression and (possibly) the body is reevaluated.

```
; Example 2
(do ([i 0 (+ i 1)])           (let loop ([i 0])
  [(= i 5)]                     (unless (= i 5)
  (display i))                     (display i)
                                   (loop (+ i 1))))
; displays: 01234
```

Now it is clear how to write a normal for loop with do:

```
for i=a to b step d         (do ([i a (+ i d)])          (let for ([i a])
  begin                       [(> i b)]                    (unless (> i b)
    exp1                      exp1                            exp1
    exp2                      exp2                            exp2
    ...                       ...)                            ...
  end                                                         (for (+ i d))))
```

The `repeat-until` loop is awkard to write using `do`, but using named let we can do as follows:

```
repeat                
  begin        (let loop ()         (let loop ()
    exp1         exp1                 exp1
    exp2         exp2                 exp2
    ...          ...                  ...
  end            (if (not test)       (unless test (loop)))
until test           (loop)))
```

This answer was based on an entry in the SchemeCookbook. See the archives: https://web.archive.org/web/20131004034526/http://schemecookbook.org/Cookbook/IdiomLoopingConstructs