# In Scheme, how can I display something multiply times?

Tags: scheme

```
`(display-n "*" 4)`

    ****
```

This code should give 4 stars. How can I display this?

Also, this code should fit in this:

Finally figured out the entire good code. Thanks for all the hints and feedback!

```
(define (display-n k n)
  (if (> n 0)
      (do ((x 0 (+ x 1)))
        ((= x n))
        (display k))))

(define (parasol n)
  (define (triangle i)
    (if (< i n)
        (begin
          (display-n " "(- n i 1))
          (display-n "*" (+ (* 2 i) 1))
          (newline)
          (triangle (+ i 1)))))
  (define (stick i)
    (if (< i 3)
        (begin
          (display-n " " (- n 1))
          (display "*") (newline)
          (stick (+ i 1)))))
  (triangle 0)
  (stick 0))

(parasol 5)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `(define (display-n x n)
    (if (> n 0)
        (begin
          (display x (- n 1))
          (newline))))` Something like this I presume? @MartinPůda

Comment: Hint: `make-string`

Comment: If you found the answers worthwhile, please upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

Phrased differently, your question is:

```
How can I repeat an operation `n` times?
```

The solution is to use a loop. In Scheme you can choose between a "named let" or a "do loop".

See detailed explanation here:

[What does the "do" control construct do in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41086158/what-does-the-do-control-construct-do-in-scheme)

Comment: `(define (display-n x n)
  (if (> n 0)
      (do ((x 0 (+ x 1)))
        ((= x n))
        (display "*"))))` I have the "right" code, buy I have to put the star in the code instead of the function. Any way to not put the star in there?

Comment: @LordCoeCoe
Replace the "*" with a a name and and the name as an argument.
Note that your counter `x` shouldn't be a parameter.
`(define (display-n n s)   (if (> n 0)       (do ((x 0 (+ x 1)))         ((= x n))         (display s))))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the ((= x n)) should be ((= x s)) in your code and it should be (display n)))) not s. Also (>  n 0) should be (> s 0). Otherwise, the code would not display 4 stars. @soegaard

Comment: I was going for `(display-n 4 "*")`. If you want the other order, swap n and s in the list of parameters. That's better tha n changing the do-expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (display-n n k)
  (if (> k 0)
      (do ((x 0 (+ x 1)))
        ((= x k))
        (display n))))
```

Found it. I'll put this here if an unfortunate soul is looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific case, since you're only outputting a single character long string, you can just make a string of n copies of that character and print it instead of using an explicit loop:

```lisp
(define (display-n k n)
  (display (make-string n (string-ref k 0))))

(display-n "*" 4)
```

or if passing a character instead of a string:

```lisp
(define (display-n k n)
  (display (make-string n k)))

(display-n #\* 4)
```

While knowing how to repeat an arbitrary task a given number of times is generally useful and probably a big point of the exercise, being able to find simpler approachs for special cases is also a good skill to have.